# Count parent rows that have children

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A has a number of rows, only some of which have (multiple) children in Table B. I need to count the rows in table A that have children.

At the moment I have

```
SELECT count(tableA.id) as count
FROM (tableA)
JOIN tableB ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id
```

Unfortunately this also counts multiple children from tableB in the count. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to put the DISTINCT keyword into your COUNT (inner join contains only rows from tableA that have children in tableB)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tableA.id) AS count
FROM (tableA)
JOIN tableB ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT count(tableA.id) as count
FROM (tableA)
where id in (select tableA_id from tableB)
```

Or, using EXISTS:

```
SELECT count(tableA.id) as count
FROM (tableA)
where exists (select 1 from tableB where tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id)
```

Comment: I find EXISTS to have better performance more often than DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives:

```
SELECT count(distinct tableA.id) as `count`
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id
```

or:

```
SELECT count(*) as `count`
FROM (tableA)
where exists
(select null from tableB where tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id)
```